# Interaction effect in ANOVA .

Tags: statistics

The statistical model for a Randomized Complete Block Design (RCBD) with multiple observations per cell is
$$y_{ijk}=\mu+\tau_{i}+\beta_{j}+(\tau\beta)_{ij}+\epsilon_{ijk},\quad i=1,\ldots ,a, \quad j=1,\ldots, b,\quad k=1,\ldots, s,
$$
where $y_{ijk}$ is a random variable that represents the response obtained on  the  $i$th treatment, the $j$th block, and $k$th observation.

If I have the following table for a RCBD with multiple observations per cell:
$$\text{Treatment}$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{Block}&\text{Brand 1} & \text{Brand 2} & \text{Brand 3} \\
\hline
\text{60 watt} & 314 & 285 & 350  \\
& 300 &296 & 339\\
\hline
\text{100 watt} & 214 & 196 &235\\
& 205 &205 &247
\end{array}
$$

$\mathbf{(1)}$Where are the interaction effects here? $\mathbf{(2)}$Does the effect lie among the observations per treatment in each block?  Or between the two blocks per treatment? Or between the pairwise treatments in each block?

$\mathbf{(3)}$How many interactions are in here?

Comment: It looks like the table depicts the predicted values from the model, not estimated coefficients. The interaction effect would be visible from your parameter estimates.